# Exclude configuration methods (e.g., @BeforeTest, @AfterTest) based on a VM arg value - Test NG

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a boolean VM arg, once it is true I would like to exclude a set of pre/post checks from the execution/ and test reports.

As a first approach, I've started with introducing a new annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExcludeFromReport {}
```

I've created a  Transformer to intercept the methods annotated with @ExcludeFromReport

```
public class ExcludeFromReportTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    private static boolean isaBoolean(Method testMethod) {
        return testMethod != null && testMethod.isAnnotationPresent(ExcludeFromReport.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, java.lang.reflect.Constructor testConstructor,
            java.lang.reflect.Method testMethod) {
        if (isMethodExcluded(testMethod)) {
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMethodExcluded(Method testMethod) {
        Log.warn("Check whether the method is excluded or not !");

        boolean isExcluded = isaBoolean(testMethod);
        Log.warn(String.format("Method = %s is excluded + %s", testMethod.getName(), isExcluded));
        return isExcluded;
    }
}
```

in my test class, I have annotated both the test method and the  configuration method  with
@ExcludeFromReport, only the  test method has been excluded, the @BeforeTest method  has been executed.

```
public class MyTestSuite {

    @BeforeTest
    @ExcludeFromReport
    public void testCase1() {
        Log.info("testCase1");
    }

    @Test
    @ExcludeFromReport
    public void testCase2() {
        Log.info("testCase2");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase3() {
        Log.info("testCase3");
    }

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, we'll need to use the broader IAnnotationTransformer interface, which allows transformation of several TestNG annotations including @Test, @BeforeTest, etc.

Modify the transformer to handle @BeforeTest, @AfterTest etc:

```
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;
import org.testng.annotations.IConfigurationAnnotation;

public class ExcludeFromReportTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    private static boolean isaBoolean(Method testMethod) {
        return testMethod != null && testMethod.isAnnotationPresent(ExcludeFromReport.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, java.lang.reflect.Constructor testConstructor,
                          java.lang.reflect.Method testMethod) {
        if (isMethodExcluded(testMethod)) {
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void transform(IConfigurationAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, 
                           java.lang.reflect.Constructor testConstructor, 
                           java.lang.reflect.Method testMethod) {
        if (isMethodExcluded(testMethod)) {
            annotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMethodExcluded(Method testMethod) {
        Log.warn("Check whether the method is excluded or not !");

        boolean isExcluded = isaBoolean(testMethod);
        Log.warn(String.format("Method = %s is excluded + %s", testMethod.getName(), isExcluded));
        return isExcluded;
    }
}
```

Ensure to add the transformer to your suite as a listener, and this solution will definitely work for u.